# Compare two databases for any differences

Tags: python, mysql

I have one mysql database on staging server and another one on production server. Initially both were exactly same. Later there were some modifications made on staging database in terms of change in schema, adding or removing some tables etc. Now I need to compare staging server's database with the production database so that I can deploy and make changes in production.

I know there are some external tools that are available for this.
But I wanted to know if I can achieve this using some mysql commands, or write python programs to do this.

Please let me know if some one knows the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do two [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)s and run `diff` `[-du]` on them.

```
$ mysqldump --databases prod > prod.sql
$ mysqldump --databases stage > stage.sql
$ diff -du stage.sql prod.sql
```

Comment: I just want to compare the schema. I do not want to compare the data. If we take the dump it will get me sql commands along with entries of data. Am I right ? Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0):

[Mysqldbcompare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html) lets you compare two databases and identify differences.

Comment: When I am trying to use "mysqldbcompare" command in Ubuntu 12.04 machine, it says command not found. I installed "mysql-workbench" also, but still same error. Any idea how to get that command in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

You can diff the tables yourself if you want to write all the code to do it, but it wouldn't be simple (I know, I've done it). If you want to go that route, you will just need to do run a `SHOW TABLES` query on each database, then run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM :table` for each table in the database and then construct the queries to update each column/table/database.

The other and probably better option is to use an existing tool. [Here's one I wrote in PHP](http://sqldiff.geneticcoder.com/), it's got an API though, or you can download the source and use it for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Following things worked for me. As I just wanted to compare the changes in schema. I did not want to compare the actual data.

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --databases --no-data staging > stage.sql
$ mysqldump -u root -p --databases --no-data production > prod.sql
$ vimdiff stage.sql prod.sql
```

Comment: This works only by chance. What if the rows returned from 2 databases are in different order?

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy there are no rows in these dumps, just structure: notice the --no-data flag